# Sql Server- Date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, reporting-services

Following a custom converter function, which convert a string values (a complete date with offset) to datetime and extract only the date part and convert extracted date part to varchar. I know this is mental. However, this is part of a data extraction and reporting (SSRS).

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(16), CONVERT(datetime,dt, 103), 20), '')
```

Where `dt` is my column where I have the “complete date time with offset” stored as string

It works as expected excluding in one case. I.e If the `dt` has no value or empty string then a part of above function (`CONVERT(datetime,dt, 103), 20)`) return a value, which is `1900/01/01`. And this `1900/01/01` subsequently convert to a string. This is sin and I don’t want any data in the final converted value of the value of dt is empty.

Question: Can someone help me to spot the issue (if any) in the above converter function. If not, who shall be the culprit here, which return 1900/01/01.

Comment: SQL Server `datetime` has a default value of `1900-01-01 00:00:00` - if you're casting an empty string to a `datetime` that's just what you'll get - run `select cast('' as datetime)` and you'll see this. What are you expecting to return?

Comment: I think the best solution is to store dates as dates, instead of strings. If you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can use the [DATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) type to store zimezone information. Please read [this article about using the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @GarethD I agree though I would argue to store in UTC time, and store timezone information separately. The big problem with DATETIMEOFFSET is that it is not DST-aware.

Comment: @IanPreston, I expect to return '' insted of 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 in case if dt is ''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `dt` with `NULLIF(dt, '')`

(Also, stop storing dates as strings. Please.)

Comment: You could write a completely wrong answer, and everyone from the Heap would probably still upvote it.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO maybe this is a completely wrong answer, then? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, The concern is, what if dt being ''. Which is equivalent of "select cast('' as datetime)" and this sql statement will return "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000". What I want is to just return '' and not 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. If I get it correct, the give answer still return 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 if the dt is ''. Please correct me.

Comment: @Nair This is exactly what Aaron's method does. [Check this example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/917e8/2), when dt is `''`, `NULLIF(dt, ''`) will return `NULL` so won't be converted to the default date of `1900-01-01`

Comment: @Nair you should try it instead of guessing what to be concerned about. :-)

Comment: What if the bad data doesn't happen to equal ''?

Comment: @Anon that just sounds like more ammunition against using the wrong data type in the first place. If you want to fix this, fix the data type!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you spot the issue:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'', 103)
```

returns 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Perhaps a case construct will help you solve the problem.  That would be my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ISDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function.  If you have SQL Server 2012, use the [TRY_CONVERT()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function.  These will defend against all bad inputs instead of just the ones you thought of in advance.